# Use Provider like a Factory

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

Can I use `Provider` in flutter like a factory constructor? I want to `watch`, `read` and `dispose` my object

Currently to watch a value we can use `context.watch<MyValue>()`, I want to watch multiple instance of `MyValue` and I want to know can provider do it for me?

```dart
class MyValue{
   final int id;

   MyValue({this.id});

}
```

I need something like

```dart
final a = context.watch<MyValue>(id:1);
final b = context.watch<MyValue>(id:2);
final c = context.watch<MyValue>(id:3);
final d = context.watch<MyValue>(id:1);

assert(a==d);
assert(a!=b);
```

If `Provider` cannot do it, How can I implement it, or is there another library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Riverpod's .family.  You can pass a parameter in just like that and create separate providers.